# Iphone - Could root.plist be referenced from another package?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, root.plist

I am a complete iOS development newbie. I am working on creating an SDK which will store preferences by the user. I need for the root.plist file be inside the SDK if possible, and to write methods for the settings from the actual app.

Answer (score 1):

The Foundation.framework already has a class that manages saving native Cocoa objects to a property list, called NSUserDefaults.

[NSUserDefaults Class Reference](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/&ei=ptk2TtaFN8jRhAeF-MT_Cg&usg=AFQjCNELtGYMqv-esEHueyGVoDDqs3bYkg&sig2=mSVoCWFDYT5zKNJDEDJQQg)

It allows you to save NSStrings, NSNumbers, NSArrays, NSDictionarys, NSData, etc. without having to worry about serializing the objects, as long as everything is either a native Cocoa object, or pre-serialized to NSData.

If this is what you are trying to do, then I would find something else you can include in your library that would differentiate it from this class; otherwise you would just be replicating existing classes.

Comment: I want to use NSUserDefaults. I am just wondering if I could move the settings bundle file to the SDK (to another package basically)